# Referencing Ajax-Loaded Element in JS Object Instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do you reference an element that doesn't exist yet from within a JavaScript object instance?

```
var Dynamic = function(el) {

  this.$instance = $(el);
}

var dynamicInstance = new Dynamic('#dynamic');
```

Since the `#dynamic` element is loaded via Ajax, the script doesn't see it when `dynamicInstance` is created and can't reference it.

If it helps solve the issue, I could also reference the element from inside the object without passing it in when it's created -- but am still unclear on how to make the object aware of the element.

Comment: What is an "object instance from an element"?  Your own object might reference DOM elements, but it's not clear what you mean by instantiating *from* a DOM element.

Comment: Good point - hopefully the edited title is more clear. Happy to expand further if it's still not clear what I'm asking.

Comment: Why don't you create your instance once the element is loaded?

Comment: Do you use `$.ajax` for your XHR? In case yes you can either use its callback to create your instance or use the jqXHR's promise interface to trigger the creation.

Comment: @m90 - yes I'm using $.ajax

Comment: @enr.code - the only way I can think to do that would be putting it in the ajax success callback, but the call is made from a separate module and they shouldn't have knowledge of each other

Comment: Accept a function callback as parameter of the function that makes the ajax call. Once the success callback function is executed, call the callback function passed as a parameter. 

In that way you keep the modules decoupled and handle the asynchronous problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep things decoupled you can accept a callback function as a parameter and call it once the new element is loaded and appended to the dom

```
function doAjaxCall(callback) {
    $.ajax({
         success : function(response) {
              //Logic to create the new element based on response
              callback();
         }  
    });
}

doAjaxCall(function() {
    var dynamic = new Dynamic('#dynamic');
});
```

In that way you keep everything decoupled while avoiding the race condition created by ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks enr.code that's fantastic - will implement it now and accept your answer as soon as I have it working

Comment: Worked beautifully. I triggered a custom event in the ajax success callback and subscribed to it in the script that creates the object instance. Thanks again.